# Unify volumes for global volume control with the rocker

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, volume

My android seems to have different volume levels for alarms, ringtone & notifications, music and games.  This is annoying/confusing for me and I'd just like one global volume control by using the volume rocker on the side of my phone.  It has happened several times that my phone would make sound when I was sure I'd silenced it, and when it happened in a job interview the other day that was the last straw!

### How can I have just one volume control?

Installing apps is OK, rooting or changing firmwares is not.

My phone is a stock Galaxy Nexus:

[image: Device details]